# SFMC Preview shows wrong subject line in Email Studio (Content Builder)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, content-builder, email-studio

An email contains HTML and Plain Text versions. Subject line is defined in code in both versions as:

```
set @Email_Subject_Line = "Original subject line"
```

Subject field is set to:

```
%%=TreatAsContent(@Email_Subject_Line)=%%
```

After updating HTML version code:

```
set @Email_Subject_Line = "Updated subject line with ' (apostrophe) for HTML version"
```

preview still shows old subject. After updating Plain text version:

```
set @Email_Subject_Line = "Updated subject line for Plain Text version"
```

preview shows subject from Plain text version. Does it mean that AMPScript variables in Plain text evaluated after HTML version and, hence, overwrite HTML version values? I don't need different subject lines for different versions but I would like to understand what's going on here, could anyone provide more details?

Comment: Hope this helps to understand the order of execution ex: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/cvvishalkumar_ampscript-order-of-execution-activity-6843337600040878080-29DX/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop

More Details by Eliot and Adam = https://ampscript.guide/order-of-operations/

Comment: To answer in short    

  -->   -->  

Comment: @vishal-kumar-c-v Thank you, that helps!